# Rails Field Validation Based on Value of Another Field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, single-table-inheritance

I need to validate that the value of a field (:discount) is one of an array of strings. The :discount field can also be blank UNLESS the :type field is 'FixedDeal' (STI)

validates :discount, inclusion: {in: VALID_DISCOUNTS}, allow_blank: true unless :type == 'FixedDeal'

The above code works to validation the value of :discount, but allows the field to be blank even if the type is 'FixedDeal'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your FixedDeal class add the following validation:

```
validates_presence_of :discount
```

That should work for you.